# Is there a better way to achieve the same results? One Page Websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to create a website with only one page but has different sections within it, you can navigate using the menu and it will scroll you to the selected section.

Here is a live preview of a website I have created using the technique you will see below: 
http://spacehopperdesign.co.uk

Please view this Fiddle for the HTML and JavaScript I am using, ignore the CSS as it does nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/J2kjA

My problem is: I want the buttons to gain the class .active when their section is shown, I know I managed to get it working as you have noticed in the live preview. But as you will see in the Fiddle, the JS I am using is a bit complex and I it is really confusing especially when working on a big project with many sections with it.

Is there anyway to achieve the same results using much simpler way? I prefer not using Plugins please. Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

Here is the JS anyway as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Prevent clicking on .active links
    'use strict'; $('.active').click(function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();
    });

    //Menu Scrolling To Sections//
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

        if (target.length) { 
            var topPadding = 50; 
        if($(window).width() > 1030) 
            topPadding = 80; 
        $('html,body').animate({ 
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - topPadding }, 700);
        return false;
        }}});
    });


    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + 200; 

    var index = $('#Index').offset().top; 
    var sectionA = $('#SectionA').offset().top; 
    var sectionB = $('#SectionB').offset().top; 
    var sectionC = $('#SectionC').offset().top; 

        $('#mainMenu li a').removeClass('active'); 

        if(scrollHeight >= index && scrollHeight < sectionA) 
        $('#index').addClass('active'); 

        if(scrollHeight >= sectionA && scrollHeight < sectionB) 
        $('#sectionA').addClass('active'); 

        if(scrollHeight >= sectionB && scrollHeight < contact) 
        $('#sectionB').addClass('active'); 

        if(scrollHeight >= sectionC) 
        $('#sectionC').addClass('active'); 
    });


});
```

and the HTML:

```
        <header id="headerWrapper">
            <div id="headerContent">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="mainMenu"><!--Main Menu-->
                        <li><a class="active" href="#Index" id="index">Welcome</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#SectionA" id="sectionA">SectionA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#SectionB" id="sectionB">SectionB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#SectionC" id="sectionC">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="page"><!--Main Container-->

            <div id="Index" class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div>  

            <div id="SectionA" class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div> 

            <div id="SectionB" class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div> 

            <div id="SectionC" class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">

                </div>
            </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: If you change your mind about the plugins, you might want to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullpage/) with the option `autoScrolling:false`.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: Take a look at this example, same as what you are looking for: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using JQuery to add a class to the button? **TESTED AND WORKS** http://jsfiddle.net/J2kjA/7/

First add another class and data to each of the buttons:

```
<li><a class="btn active" data-btn="index" href="#Index" id="index">Welcome</a></li>
<li><a class="btn" data-btn="sectionA" href="#SectionA" id="sectionA">SectionA</a></li>
<li><a class="btn" data-btn="sectionB" href="#SectionB" id="sectionB">SectionB</a></li>
<li><a class="btn" data-btn="sectionC" href="#SectionC" id="sectionC">Contact</a></li>
```

And for the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Prevent clicking on .active links
'use strict'; $('.active').click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
});

//Menu Scrolling To Sections//
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

            if (target.length) { 
                var topPadding = 50; 
                if($(window).width() > 1030) 
                topPadding = 80; 
                $('html,body').animate({ 
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - topPadding }, 700);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });


$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + 200; 
    var index = $('#Index').offset().top; 
    var sectionA = $('#SectionA').offset().top; 
    var sectionB = $('#SectionB').offset().top; 
    var sectionC = $('#SectionC').offset().top; 

    });
}); 


$(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        var btn = $(this).data("btn");
        $('#index').removeClass("active");
        $('#sectionA').removeClass("active");
        $('#sectionB').removeClass("active");
        $('#sectionC').removeClass("active");
        $('#'+btn).addClass ("active");
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: Sorry I missed out a bracket `var btn = $(this).data("btn");`

Comment: Also remember to add the line `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"</script>` and the link to the jquery code into your `<head>` tags

Comment: Please can you update the fiddle? it is not working :/ I know i am doing something wrong,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42034/discussion-between-leo-and-smj2393)

Comment: If this has been answered, make one of the answers as your selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this function for you:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

This checks if an element is visible after scrolling. You can call it whenever the page is scrolled and check whatever you need for each of the elements.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if(isScrolledIntoView($('#SectionA'))){
        $('#sectionA').addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is sorts working, however the buttons in the navigation should also gain the class .active not only on click but when you are physically scrolling and their section appears.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#mainMenu a').click(function() {
    $('#mainMenu a').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });

   if(scrollHeight >= index && scrollHeight < sectionA) 
    {$('#index').trigger('click');} //etc

  });
```

Comment: This will only add class active to the buttons when clicked n them only :/

Comment: Trigger a click with the scroll height.